# Switched from nVidia to Radeon GPU. Now my screen is all garbled. How do I install the driver?

Tags: graphics, radeon

I found [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver), but it doesn't seem to address actually installing anything, just configuration and whether you can use some unmentioned tool or not. I tried doing a software update, the hardware drivers application does nothing, and I'm thinking the easiest thing to do might be just to back up my home folder and reinstall. Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fighting with the ATI proprietary drivers (could never get them installed and working correctly), open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for "x.org ati". Works a charm for Radeon boards.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did it this morning, but after installation through the Software Center, nothing happened. So I went into Administration and found a newly-available Catalyst Center, which I started, but was stopped by an error message telling me that it can't start because it can't find the driver. I thought it *was* the driver, so I'm just as confused as before. What additional steps do I have to take?

Comment: Just a note that the ATI proprietary drivers only support newer ATI card (HD series) on newer distros. ATI stop development of drivers for older cards at Catalyst 9.3. See [this ATI Link](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Legacy/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.12&lang=English) for a list of effected cards. These older legacy drivers only work with older ubuntu distros. So for older cards with newer distros the open source drivers are the only choice.